# join only the last result from linq query

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, entity-framework-core

```cs
var decisionStatus = repo<FOTreeDetailsDocsEntity>().Queryable()
    .Where(s => s.TreeDetailsID == treeDetailsLineId)
    .Join(_untracked<FOTreeDetailsDocsStatusEntity>(),
        s => s.Id, 
        c => c.FOTreeDetailsDocs, 
        (s, c) => new { doc = s, status = c }).DistinctBy(x => x.status.DecisionReasonTypeID)
    .Join(_untracked<DecisionReasonTypeEntity>(),
        d => d.status.DecisionReasonTypeID,
        s => s.Id,
        (d, s) => new { decisionStatus = d, decisionType = s }
    ).ToArray();
```

Hi,
using the following query how can I add condition of"last or default" for the first line of the query?
lets say I have on  `repo<FOTreeDetailsDocsEntity>().Queryable().Where(s => s.TreeDetailsID == treeDetailsLineId)` two results and I want to join other tables(the rest of the query) only on the last result. how can I do it?

Comment: Try `OrderByDescending` with `FirstOrDefault`

Answer (score 0):

In order to get the last result of the query, you can use the chaining of OrderByDescending() by some property and FirstOrDefault() methods:

```
var decisionStatus = repo<FOTreeDetailsDocsEntity>().Queryable()
    .Where(s => s.TreeDetailsID == treeDetailsLineId)
    .Join(_untracked<FOTreeDetailsDocsStatusEntity>(),
        s => s.Id, 
        c => c.FOTreeDetailsDocs, 
        (s, c) => new { doc = s, status = c }).DistinctBy(x => x.status.DecisionReasonTypeID)
    .Join(_untracked<DecisionReasonTypeEntity>(),
        d => d.status.DecisionReasonTypeID,
        s => s.Id,
        (d, s) => new { decisionStatus = d, decisionType = s }
    )
    .OrderByDescending(x => x.SomeProperty)
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

In such a way, it will be translated to

```
SELECT TOP 1 your_data FROM tables with joins ORDER BY some_property DESC
```

The only note with this approach is that you need to order your data by some property, since T-SQL has only `SELECT TOP` operator and there is no something like `SELECT BOTTOM` operator so to get the the values from the bottom you need to order your query in descending order by some column/columns.